# I have no idea why these SQL command doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have an Xampp server with phpmyadmin and I usered this command, which always worked:

```
WITH temptable AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY character_ID DESC) 
AS t FROM characters) SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE t BETWEEN 0 AND 10;
```

Now I got a database on a real server and it doesent work anymore. So I looked for other commands on the internet and always found this one on several websites:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Character_ID ASC) AS t,
  Charactername
FROM characters WHERE t < 5;
```

I looked over several websites and it doesnt work for me and i dont know why.
The syntax in Phpmyadmin doesnt mark anything wrong when i write this command but i got still the error: 
*You have an error in your SQL syntax;*

Maybe someone knows why?

Comment: It's shouldn't *just* be saying you have an error. It should be giving you a hint about where the error is and it should be suggesting you check the manual for your version of MySQL/MariaDB. So, have you done so?

Comment: Tag your question with the database and version that you are using.

Comment: I guess the RDBMS is MySQL. **Window functions** (that you are using here) were introduced in version 8. It is thus possible that your local server is running MySQL 8 and your production server is still for instance on MySQL 5. Have  you checked your versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter by columns defined in the `SELECT`.  If you are using MySQL (or MariaDB), you can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Character_ID ASC) AS t,
       Charactername
FROM characters 
HAVING t < 5;
```

These databases extend the use of the `HAVING` clause for non-aggregation queries, and it allows the use of column aliases for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering aggregation doesn't work that way in select.Modify your query as below,

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Character_ID ASC) AS t,
  Charactername
FROM characters) Characternametab
 WHERE t < 5;
```